# Why notification use the res of mipmap as smallIcon will crash system ui in Android O?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-mipmap

If I use the **`mipmap`** icon as `smallIcon` of a `Notification` in **`Android O`**, when notify it, the system ui will crash. But it works below O, and if I change the icon with res in `drawable` directory, it works as well. Although Google tell us we should place our app icons in `mipmap` dirs, why I can not use it as the `notification` icon in Android O?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Probably just [a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69109923).

Comment: @CommonsWare I find that below `Android O`, the result of `getDrawable` from `mipmap` res is `BitmapDrawable`, and on `Android O` it is `AdaptiveIconDrawable`, and it makes `createBitmap` fail during notification execution flow.